# How to set default value for EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

May I know how to set default value for EntityManager? For example, I want EntityManager default to be "A" without modifying the line `@PersistenceContext` to `@PersistenceContext(unitName="A")`. I need to do this because I am not able to edit the line of @PersistenceContext (a jar file from other project). I tried @Primary but it does not work.

```
// editable
@Bean(name = "A")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfA() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    ...
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("A");
    ...
    return em;
}

// editable
@Bean(name = "B")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfB() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    ...
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("B");
    ...
    return em;
}

// not editable
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: What currently happens when you use your configuration (i.e. with an EM marked `@Primary`)?

Comment: Hi @Dovmo, it will hit `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
expected single matching bean but found 2: A,B`, I think `@Primary` not working with `@PersistenceContext`

Answer (score 0):

One of the Spring guys made a demo on [exactly how to do this](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/demo-multi-entity-managers). It looks like you will need to specify the packages exactly where the entity manager should be applied. You will need to do that in:

1. `@EnableJpaRepositories` with the `basePackages` or `basePackageClasses` properties and also...
2. The `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder#packages` builder call

In his example, looks like:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "orderEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "orderTransactionManager",
        basePackageClasses = Order.class)
```

and

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean orderEntityManager(
        JpaProperties orderJpaProperties) {
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(
            orderJpaProperties);
    return builder
            .dataSource(orderDataSource())
            .packages(Order.class)
            .persistenceUnit("ordersDs")
            .build();
}
```